# openshift origin with local docker registry

Tags: docker, openshift

Am new to openshift and am trying a basic setup. I have docker and openshift installed on my Ubuntu VM inside my windows laptop. I dont have any problem in using docker alone and pushing or pulling from my local registry. I have problem in using the oc new-app command in the openshift origin.

I have a local registry running in my VM

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
26d3a527398d        registry:2          "/bin/registry serve "   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

and I have pushed a image to this registry

```
docker images myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu   latest              cf62323fa025        7 days ago          125 MB
```

When i try to use this image in the openshift, am getting below error

```
./oc new-app --docker-image=myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu
error: can't look up Docker image "myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu": Internal error occurred: Get https://myregistry.com:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
error: no match for "myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu"

The 'oc new-app' command will match arguments to the following types:

  1. Images tagged into image streams in the current project or the 'openshift' project
     - if you don't specify a tag, we'll add ':latest'
  2. Images in the Docker Hub, on remote registries, or on the local Docker engine
  3. Templates in the current project or the 'openshift' project
  4. Git repository URLs or local paths that point to Git repositories

--allow-missing-images can be used to point to an image that does not exist yet.

See 'oc new-app -h' for examples.
```

Is this something to do with my DNS resolution ? How can I use my local registry inside my openshift origin

Comment: Is ``myregistry.com`` resolvable from inside of the VM where OpenShift is running?

Comment: How did you install OpenShift? (Are you running it in a docker container?) Because the advanced installation will require RHEL or CentOS

Answer (score 1):

The code in [`openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/auth.go#authenticateToRegistry()`](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/8d2b7b2d1ab5fa3cc8d14cc745b96352cae67576/pkg/diagnostics/pod/auth.go#L145-L147) mentions:

```
    case strings.Contains(secError.Error(), "tls: oversized record received"),
    strings.Contains(secError.Error(), "server gave HTTP response to HTTPS"):
            r.Debug("DP1015", "docker-registry not secured; falling back to cleartext connection")
```

[Issue 6516](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/6516) mentions:

> if your registry requires authentication, then that is the problem. new-app cannot pull images from registries that require authentication (there is an existing issue for this), so as far as it's concerned the image does not exist in the registry.

[Issue 6540](https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/6540) (OC 1.1.1) is supposed to resolve this:

> `new-app` can use an image that appears to only exist locally (because new-app can't access the registry). It will proceed to define the expected openshift objects (`deploymentconfig`, etc) with a reference to that image.
>   If the nodes are also not able to pull the image, the deployment will ultimately still fail. (however unlike `new-app`, `nodes` are able to pull images from secure registries)

---

The [OP Raghavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790126/raghavan) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407363/openshift-origin-with-local-docker-registry/38407827?noredirect=1#comment64598921_38407827) having setup the DNS with "[How to Setup a DNS Server for a Home Lab on Ubuntu 14.04](http://frankhinek.com/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-for-a-home-lab-on-ubuntu-14-04/)"

> I added the DNS and `--insecure-registry` option in `/etc/default/docker` file as

```
DOCKER_OPTS=--dns 10.0.3.1 --insecure-registry ns1.myregistry.com:5000
```

> Here `10.0.3.1` was my DNS server and also the server where docker registry is running with hostname as `ns1.myregistry.com`

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem was with my DNS resolution.

Comment: I brought up a DNS server using this link - http://frankhinek.com/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-for-a-home-lab-on-ubuntu-14-04/   and added the DNS and --insecure-registry option in /etc/default/docker file as DOCKER_OPTS=--dns 10.0.3.1 --insecure-registry ns1.myregistry.com:5000" . Here 10.0.3.1 was my DNS server and also the server where docker registry is running with hostname as ns1.myregistry.com

Comment: @Raghavan I have added your explanations to the answer for more visibility.